# Uninstalling Chrome completely - How to?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, uninstall

I plan to uninstall Chrome completely. How can I do it?

When I say completely, I mean all of the profile related data, the cached files, the settings, everything.

Does the default uninstall (via Add/Remove programs) do all of the above and more?

My operating system is Windows 7 x64.

**EDIT**

I found these two links [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95319) and [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=111899).

I am going to attempt both of these, I will let you know how it proceeds shortly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html) is perfect for this. It has options for how extreme an uninstall you want to do. Choose the most comprehensive one.

Comment: +1 for a working solution! Thanks! But, do I have to install another product to uninstall an existing one? Instead, is there an alternate solution? How would I fare if I just went ahead and deleted the folder C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google

Comment: @Kanini: you would still have a lot of left over junk in the computer...

Comment: @studiohack: Thanks! And, how do I get ride of all that left over junk?

Comment: @Kanini: I agree with @nrhine1: Revo Uninstaller is a very good tool for this kind of thing.  well worth the install...I use it all the time myself, and it just finds and cleans so much junk!

Answer (score -1):

[Iobit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html) is a light and FREE tool that helps you to remove unwanted programs and folders without any hassle and I use all the time when needing to remove programs from my PC (instead of using the default Add/Remove Programs option in Windows Explorer).

Features include:

- Remove Unwanted Programs and Folders Super Fast
- 1-Click Removal of Annoying Stubborn Toolbars
- No More Leftovers with **"Powerful Scan"** and **"Forced Uninstall"**
- Portable version also available

It works along similar lines as the aforementioned Revo Uninstaller as mentioned by @nrhine1.