# Chrome option to save passwords greyed out

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, passwords

A colleague of mine is having issues with Google Chrome. The option to have Chrome save passwords is not available, the tick box and label are both greyed out. Chrome was previously saving the passwords, the problem has occurred in the last couple of weeks. The problem didn't occur when the PC was upgraded to Windows 10.

Google Chrome version 46.0.2490.71 m
Windows 10

From my research online (both via Google and [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/573602/google-chrome-not-saving-passwords-and-not-auto-filling-existing-login-password)) I have thus far:

- Reset the synchronisation with my colleague's Google account.
- Ensured Auto-fill is enabled.
- Ensured local Cookies are allowed.

I have also checked that the registry keys for Google Chrome in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` don't have the ability to save the password explicitly denied. The policy to allow Google to save passwords was not enabled there, but attempting to create the relevant keys has failed to resolve the issue (as I expected from my research in the Google products forum where I discovered that potential problem).

The registry solution is also proposed [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/769264/google-chrome-save-web-passwords-option-is-disabled), however this seems to affect an earlier version of Chrome/Windows, I have tried creating the specified keys - however searching the registry on another machine with the same Windows/Chrome versions doesn't show any results to match the `PasswordManagerEnabled` value anywhere.

I am aware that uninstalling and reinstalling Google Chrome usually fails to reset these settings. I know it's possible to entirely remove all traces of a former installation of Google Chrome before reinstalling, this is something I don't want to have to go through unnecessarily as everything I have read on this problem implies that doing so will not resolve this problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem recently and found a working solution?

**//Edit**
I have since posting this question;

- Reinstalled Chrome using the software in [this
  question](https://superuser.com/questions/220958/uninstalling-chrome-completely-how-to).
- Unsynched Chrome from my colleague's Google account.
- Resynched Chrome with my colleague's Google account.
- Checked through *every* option in the Google account section on
  devices.
- Updated the Google account to require a passphrase (just in case).

All, thus far, to no avail.

**//Edit - Further update**

Installed Canary on the same PC, same issue with that. I am lead to believe that it may be an issue with Windows and not Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not helpful to many other people, unless you have an HP PC.

The problem was with some bundled software on the PC. Specifically HP Simple Pass (which was never used and neither I nor my colleague were aware of it even being on that PC).

Uninstalling it resolved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

My option to save passwords always greyed out and disabled but it should allow you to ask for existing username/passwords saved from your Google account.  From `chrome://settings/passwords` > `Autofill` just make sure to login into your Google account then click on the show button to view usernames and passwords as per the following screen.

[image: Make sure to login into your Google account]

**Note: The only inconvenient I found is that I can only manually add new record(s) by Exporting passwords to a csv file and add/modify it from the CSV file then Importing it back when it is done.**